# How do I find the developing time for Fomapan 400 using Fomatol P (Bromophen)?

Tags: film, developing

I need to develop a Fomapan 400 film using Fomatol P (Bromophen). Does anybody know where should I look for the developing time charts? The film is in black and white.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help! Since I only had Fomatol P (which is a paper developer, as pointed by Jindra) I made a test and it worked! 9 minutes at 26 degrees Celsius. I don't know if this is luck or what but it works.

Comment: Do you happen to have a scan of the result? The theory why it should look no good is strong, but seeing is believing and I am a curious person :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you can not find the time chart because it does not exist.

Long answer: [Fomatol P](http://www.foma.cz/en/paper), which is a clone of [Ilford Bromophen](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/amfile/file/download/file_id/755/product_id/582/) - I am including link to both product sheets - is a **paper** developer.

What you need is a **film** developer. The concentration of chemicals in film and paper developers is greatly different, to such an extent that they are not interchangeable.

To develop your Fomapan 400 you need to buy a film developer. Fomatol P will not do.

Answer (score 1):

The top result¹ returned from [Googling](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Fomapan%20400%20film%20using%20Fomatol%20P%20(Bromophen)) *'Fomapan 400 film using Fomatol P (Bromophen)'* is a link to the [PDF spec sheet](http://www.foma.cz/en/fomapan-400) for Fomapan 400.

Included in the spec sheet is the information you are seeking.

[image]

Or maybe not. From a comment by [Jindra Lacko](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/62463/jindra-lacko)

> Pointing to google is fun, but you should have noticed the slightly different spelling of Fomatol P vs Fomadon P. These are two different developers.

If someone else finds this question and really means 'Fomadon P', rather than 'Fomatol P', the information they need is in the chart above. 'Fomatol P' is not suitable for developing film.

<sub>¹ At least, *before* this answer was posted, it was.</sub>

Comment: Well, _now_, the top result is _this question_.

Comment: @mattdm LOL!!!!

Comment: Pointing to google is fun, but you should have noticed the slightly different spelling of *Fomatol P* vs *Fomadon P*. These are two different developers, and your answer is wrong.

Comment: @JindraLacko Nice catch!

Comment: @MichaelClark I am Czech, and Foma is my "home brand" :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is screen shot from the massive dev chart.

i could not find Fomatol P on it, perhaps you meant Fomadon P ?

[image: Fomapan 400 with Foma developers]

A great resource.

[The Massive Dev Chart](https://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php)